# Celery logging not saving std out

Tags: python, celery

I run celery (for django) with:

```
celery worker -A workerTasks -n Worker%h --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info -Q office -f $WORKER_LOG_FILE --pidfile=/logs/worker_pid%h.pid
```

The python output is saved in the file.

However, if I run a bash command from python with subprocess.call and that bash command gives std output, it is not saved in the log file.

Is it possible for me to capture that output, either in the celery log file or via another method?

Thank you

Comment: You have to capture the output yourself, and use Celery logger to write it down.

Comment: this should help you : https://gist.github.com/bgreenlee/1402841

Comment: Ok so I'm using
'''
child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ret = child.wait()
print(child.communicate()[0])
'''
which works, but some of my outputs are huuuge and I'd rather handle line by line if possible? Can I read from the pipe one line at a time?